# Authentication with database in Flexisip (Linphone SIP server)

Tags: sip, linphone

I successfully installed Flexisip on server CentOS 7.
But now I cannot config Authentication of Flexisip with database MySQL

My database has table users 'flexisip_users' with columns: id, username, password (not hashed).

This is my config:

```
[module::Authentication]
enabled=true
db-implementation=odbc
datasource==DRIVER={MySQL};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=voicechat;USER=root;PASSWORD=abc2016@123;OPTION=3;
hashed-passwords=false
request=select password from flexisip_users where username = :id
```

if I using db-implementation=file, authentication perfect working. But when i switch to 'odbc' with above config, client receive error "Internal server error'.

how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Install the required packages:

`yum install -y bc-unixODBC bc-mysql-connector-odbc`

And in your configuration file `flexisip.conf` your driver should be:

`DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}`

Or whatever you have in your `/etc/bc-unixODBC/odbcinst.ini` file.